# WiFi network disconnects automatically, then no WiFi networks are visible in the scanning list

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I am a novice on Ubuntu 22.04. My laptop connects to WiFi networks fine, but after some time it disconnects automatically. Then no WiFi networks are visible in the scanning list. After restarting the laptop it connects to WiFi networks fine, again after some time it disconnects automatically. Then again no WiFi networks are visible in the scanning list. Note that, all the programs are up to date, so no additional drivers are available.

Here are the logs:

```
rtw_8822be failed to read ASPM
rtw_8822be failed to power on mac
rtw_8822be failed to poll offset=0x5 mask=0x2 value=0x0
```

Laptop model: Lenovo Ideapad S340-14IWL

WiFi adapter: Realtek RTL8822BE

How to fix this problem?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyMye.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try changing the power management mode of the Network Manager in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` from 2 to 3, so that it looks like this:

`wifi.powersave = 3`

Also, check if there is a UEFI update for your laptop.

PS: I don't think you need to change the default kernel right away.

Comment: I changed the power management mode. Tried both '2' and '3' for 'wifi.powersave ='. But nothing worked. I also checked UEFI update, but no updates are available.

Now the update is my laptop connects to wifi networks normally, but there is no internet access. Can you suggest me another solution?